# Link forks to project on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I made a new project on GitHub whose sole purpose is to link/group repositories that are related to same topic, ex:

1. Project name: `cpp-math`
2. Project repos: random math repos, both owned by me and forked ones, as well as those hosted on other domains such as GitLab.

I figured out only owned repositories can be linked, forks can't.

as for repositories located on other domains such as GitLab, I plan to push my GitLab fork from GitLab to GitHub, and maintain 2 remotes, just to be able to group all math stuff in one place, in that case these would be considered as "owned" from GitHub perspective, so not a problem.

However repositories forked on GitHub can't be linked, I want to avoid making them "owned" ie. by creating own repository and then pushing the fork into it.

So the question is how to link GitHub forks to projects?